# PHP pdo remote connection to Oracle error

Tags: php, oracle, pdp

I have been trying to connect remotely to oracle using pdo 
I have enable pdo driver

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

But getting this error

> ***"SQLSTATE[HY000]: OCIEnvNlsCreate: Check the character set is valid and that PHP has access to Oracle libraries and NLS data (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:614)"***

Here is my code for connection

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("oci:dbname='My server ip'/orcl;charset=UTF-8", "my user name", "my password");

    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {     echo $e->getMessage();     }
```

Comment: `putenv("NLS_LANG=.WE8ISO8859P1");`

Comment: tried bit error stile same!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errormessage after I installed multiple copies of ODAC/ODT because I didn't know what version I needed to have my Visual Studio projects (Windows Forms app and a ASP.NET website) connect to a Oracle database. While fixing this connection problem in the end, I broke my PHP/PDO website which also needed to connect to the same Oracle database. It gave me the same errormessage as in your question.
I removed all ODAC/ODT client installations and also the Oracle Server to be sure and then I reinstalled only the Oracle Server (in my case Oracle 11.2 Express 64bit) and it worked again. I could connect again from SQL Developer and also through PHP/PDO. After that I installed the correct ODAC/ODT (32bit(!) version because of my 32bit Visual Studio) and now also my Visual Studio Forms project AND ASP.NET website could connect to the Oracle server.